# Xcode7 localization plist file crash

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, localization

I need to localize my plist files and string files for my project. However, when I try to select other languages in file inspector for .plist files, the Xcode will crash.

```html
Parent Process:        ??? [1]
Responsible:           Xcode [1981]
User ID:               501

Date/Time:             2015-09-24 11:47:52.069 +1000
OS Version:            Mac OS X 10.10.4 (14E46)
Report Version:        11
Anonymous UUID:        XXXXXXXXXXX


Time Awake Since Boot: 7500 seconds

Crashed Thread:        0  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread

Exception Type:        EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes:       0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000

Application Specific Information:
ProductBuildVersion: 7A220
UNCAUGHT EXCEPTION (NSInvalidArgumentException): *** -[NSPathStore2 stringByAppendingPathExtension:]: nil argument
UserInfo: (null)
Hints: None
Backtrace:
  0  0x00007fff89f71024 __exceptionPreprocess (in CoreFoundation)
  1  0x0000000102627744 DVTFailureHintExceptionPreprocessor (in DVTFoundation)
  2  0x00007fff87bc376e objc_exception_throw (in libobjc.A.dylib)
  3  0x00007fff89f70eed +[NSException raise:format:] (in CoreFoundation)
  4  0x00007fff90f257e3 -[NSPathStore2 stringByAppendingPathExtension:] (in Foundation)
  5  0x000000010c5ae87c -[Xcode3VariantGroup proposedFilePathForLocalization:fileType:] (in DevToolsCore)
  6  0x000000011281dc8c -[Xcode3LocalizationCommands
```

Anyone has same issue with Xcode7??

PS: localizing .string file works fine with same approach.

Answer (score 0):

Having the same issue. Xcode 7.1 beta 2 seems to have it fixed.